# Use TransferManager to upload directory to s3 in Java failed without exception

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am using TransferManager to upload a directory (including large number of files 10k ~ 100k count) to s3 and I found that sometimes the upload maybe failed or stuck without any exception or success handler. The log just show that it started to upload to s3 but it never show it finished or failed.

I show my code below, hope someone can help me figure out what is going wrong.

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity upload(
    @RequestPart("file") @Valid
    MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
  try {
    File dest = File.createTempFile(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), "zip");
    if (!dest.getParentFile().exists()) {
      Files.createDirectories(dest.getParentFile().toPath());
    }
    file.transferTo(dest);
    CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
      try {
        long size = fileUploadService
            .upload(new FileInputStream(dest),uploadDescriptor.getTargetPath());
        if (size <= 0) {
          log.fail();
        } else {
          log.success();
        }
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        log.fail();
        log.error(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return dest.delete();
    }, executor);
  } catch (IOException e) {
    log.error(e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

  return ResponseEntity.accepted().build();
}
```

And here is the `FileUploadService`:

```
public class FileUploadService {

  private StorageService storageService;

  @Autowired
  public FileUploadService(StorageService storageService) {
    this.storageService = storageService;
  }

  public long upload(InputStream inputStream, String path) {
    try {
      Path tempDirectory = Files.createTempDirectory(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
      unzip(inputStream, tempDirectory);
      long size = FileUtils.sizeOfDirectory(tempDirectory.toFile());
      boolean isSuccess = storageService.storeDir(tempDirectory.toFile(), path);
      FileSystemUtils.deleteRecursively(tempDirectory);
      return isSuccess ? size : -1;
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      log.error("failed to update to {}", path);
      log.error(e.getMessage());
      return -1;
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the `StorageService`:

```
@Slf4j
public class StorageService {

  private static final String SUFFIX = "/";
  private S3Configuration configuration;
  private final AmazonS3 s3Client;

  @Autowired
  public S3StorageService(S3Configuration configuration) {
    this.configuration = configuration;
    BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials(
        configuration.getAccessKey(), configuration.getAccessSecret());
    s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
        .withRegion(configuration.getRegion())
        .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCreds))
        .build();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean storeDir(File file, String fullPath) {
    log.info("start upload from {} to {}", file.toString(), fullPath);
    TransferManager manager = TransferManagerBuilder.standard().withS3Client(s3Client).build();
    try {
      MultipleFileUpload xfer = manager.uploadDirectory(configuration.getBucketName(),
                                                        fullPath, file, true);
      xfer.waitForCompletion();
      log.info("finish upload from {} to {}", file.toString(), fullPath);
      return true;
    } catch (AmazonServiceException | InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      log.error("failed to update from {} to {}", file.toString(), fullPath);
      log.error(e.getMessage());
      return false;
    } finally {
      manager.shutdownNow(false);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly does running this log?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you rather try "waitForException"? Or better still monitor the progress so you can see how far it gets and check for errors/completion at the end, and when it does finish, check the state for errors etc.